# Using Flags in CopyHere method in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to VbScript, and I'm trying to create a script that copies in background some files, though it shows me the progress bar while it's copying, and I don't want to see that. I'm using the Folder.CopyHere method, so I saw on  [Microsoft DevCenter Documentation - CopyHere method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that there's a way to use flag to hide the progress bar window. I looked all around the internet but I couldn't find anything that explains how to use those flags. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flags a collection of bit values.

```
0001 = 1
0010 = 2
0100 = 4
1000 = 8
```

So if you want bit 1 and 3 set

```
0101 = 5
```

We normally refer to bits by their hex value, although your documentation uses decimal (0 for none, 2, 4, 8, 16 (&h10 or 0x10), 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc).

Add numbers together to set multiple flags.